# How to find a bug that only happens in the Javascript version of a Dart program?

Tags: debugging, dart, angular-dart, code-translation

I've written a program that runs perfectly in Dart but fails to run in the transpiled Javascript version. I suspect it's an infinite loop (because CPU usage goes up). Has anybody experienced such a behavior before? Maybe even more important, how can I find out the problem?

Comment: What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: Have you checked the console output of the developer tools of the browser for error messages?.  
When you build with `pub build --mode=debug` you get readable JavaScript and can use the debugger of the developer tools.

Comment: @Günther: that was exacatly the hint I was looking for. Thanks!

Yes, of course I've checked the console. It's empty. Most likely the debug flag will help me. Too bad it doesn't seem to be possible to activate it in DartEditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart can generate source maps since a while which makes it quite easy to debug generated JS. 
With source maps the browsers show Dart code and stack traces when debugging built JS code.

Source maps need to be enabled in the browser (see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dart2js/ for details) and in the $dart2js transformer (see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html for details)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; this is a big part of my day job.

First, understand that you are most likely dealing with a dart2js bug, not a bug in your code.  Your immediate goal is to work around the problem.  The end goal, though, is to construct a small test case that you can file on dartbug.com.

**Checked mode is your friend**

If you are really lucky, **enabling checked mode** will throw an assertion that will point to the problem.  If not, you'll need to dig into the JS.

Using `pub serve` or `pub build --mode=debug` will give you more readable code.  I usually set my pubspec.yaml up like so:

```
transformers:
- $dart2js:
  minify: false
  checked: true
```

(or checked=false if I'm chasing a performance issue).  Then running `pub build` (without any arguments) will produce to desired output.

**Produce a smaller use-case**

If you can get Angular out of the mix, the Dart Team will have a much easier time debugging.  Failing that, generate a AngularDart application that shows the error on page load.

**Print statements**

Adding print statements in Dart help you understand the execution flow, but also make it easy to search the dart2js output for good places to add breakpoints.

I find that source maps only confuse things and always disable them.

**git bisect**

Once you have a small enough use-case that triggers on page load, using git bisect to search your history for the breaking change is quick and impresses your friends.

Comment: More options on $dart2js can be found at [the pub documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html).

Comment: As it seems the transformers should not be the last entry in pubspec.yaml. After some trying, [this version](https://github.com/stephanrauh/AngularPrime-Dart/blob/master/pubspec.yaml) worked fine with me.  
(Sorry for giving a link to my repository, I'd prefer to show it here, but formatting doesn't seem to work in a comment).

Comment: I like the "print statement" hint. Such a simple idea, and so useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can get readable JavaScript by running `dart2js` in debug mode. If you are using `pub build` you need to use `pub build --mode=debug`.